# Add a credit card to customers paypal wallet

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Is it possible to add a customer's credit card information to their Paypal Wallet? I've looked into the REST API, but the information is stored in a vault specific to a merchant. I want to save the card information to the customer's wallet for future use. Does Paypal have a wallet api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, no.  The buyer has to log in to their PayPal account to add the card.

(There is the AddPaymentCard API, but this is typically reserved for banks that are setting up PayPal accounts for their users and are adding a credit card/debit card, that they issued, to the new account.)